# How to switch Oval Shape backcolor after clicking on it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, color-coding

So thats my code, it works with a button but it doesnt work with my OvalShape. I need it for a Master Mind game in C#. The Oval shape should Change the Color after clicking on it. Its supposed  to be able to Change into 6 Colors Red,Yellow,Blue,White,Green and Purple.

```
     private void ovalShape1_4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control ctrl = ((Control)sender);
        switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
        {
            case "Red":
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;
            case "Black":
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
            case "White":
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case "Yellow":
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Purple;
                break;
            default:
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;





using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks;

namespace Mastermind2
{
    public static class ControlCollectionExtension
    {
        public static IList<OvalShape> ToList(this ShapeCollection aiShapeCollection)
        {
            IList<OvalShape> aoShapes = new List<OvalShape>();

            foreach (OvalShape ctrl in aiShapeCollection)
                aoShapes.Add(ctrl);

            return aoShapes;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly 1 click= for example Red, second click = Yellow... and so on

Comment: Append your code showing where you added the handler to the shape.

Comment: can you share ovalshape class or control

Comment: BackColor does not do what you think it does.  Use FillColor instead.  That requires casting *sender* to OvalShape.

Answer (score 0):

make public variable

```
int index = 0;
```

after that make this logic, may this help you

```
 private void ovalShape1_4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
OvalShape ctrl = ((OvalShape)sender);
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;
            case 1:
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
            case 2:
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case 3:
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Purple;
                break;
            default:
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                index = 0;
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: This would not work unless the click event also changed the value of `index`. Since there are multiple instances of the shape controls, you'd need to have multiple `index` variables defined. I believe the OP is trying to use the color property of the control to determine what the next could should be.

Comment: yes! you are right, this doesn't work for multiple OvalShape.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have no Click event handler assigned to the OvalShape controls.

```
   foreach (OvalShape ctrl in aiShapeCollection)
      ctrl.Click += ovalShape1_4_Click;
      aoShapes.Add(ctrl);
```